# Prove any proper initial segment of $Ord\setminus S$ is a set.

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Here $Ord\setminus S$ denotes the class we get by remove a set of ordinals from $Ord$ class.
I am asking for a formal proof of any proper initial segment of $Ord\setminus S$ is a set.

I have tried as follows:

For any proper initial segment $I_S(\alpha)=\lbrace x|x<\alpha, x\in  Ord\setminus S\rbrace$ of  $Ord\setminus S$ for some $\alpha\in  Ord \setminus S$, Note that $I_S(\alpha)=\lbrace x|x<\alpha, x\in  Ord\setminus S\rbrace \subseteq  I(\alpha)=\lbrace x|x<\alpha, x\in Ord \rbrace$ , and  $I(\alpha)=\lbrace x|x<\alpha, x,\alpha\in Ord \rbrace$ is a initial segment of Ord and hence a set we conclude that the subclass $I_S(\alpha)$ of $I(\alpha)$ is a set.

But latter I noticed that not all the initial segments are in this form. So how should I fix it? Could someone tell me how to deal with that? Thanks!

EDIT:
The definition of initial segment in my text is:
[image]
Now it is my attempt:
For any proper initial segment $X$ of $Ord\setminus S$ , by definition of initial segment, for some $x\in  Ord$, it is a collection such that $x ∈X$ and $\forall a\in Ord\setminus S, a ≤ x ⇒ a∈X$. As $Ord\setminus S \subseteq Ord$, for that fixed $x$, it is a subcollection of the collection $Y$ such that $x\in Y$ and $\forall a\in Ord, a ≤ x ⇒ a∈Y$. That is, for any initial segment $X$ of $Ord\setminus S, X\subseteq Y$ for some initial segement $Y$ of $Ord$. Thus any proper initial segment of  $Ord\setminus S$ is a subset of a set. Thus it is a set.

But now I realize that I have not prove that the proper initial segment must be a subclass of a proper initial segment other then the whole $Ord$ class.Could someone please help here?

Comment: What is $Ord \setminus S$?

Comment: @user49640 It is the ordinal class minus a subset of it.

Comment: Okay, you mean a proper initial segment, right?

Comment: @user49640 I do know that $Ord $ is a proper class. I am proving a statement about the initial segment.

Comment: @user49640 Yes.

Comment: What you call $I_S(\alpha)$ is really just $\alpha - S$, which is a subclass of $\alpha$, hence a set.

Comment: @user49640 I believe that is true. And now I fell a little stuck on how to formally prove it. And it is actually one thing I am asking about. And also note that there maybe other forms of initial segments.

Comment: What is the definition of an initial segment of a well-ordered set $E$ for you? For me it's either $E$ or a set of the form $I_a = \{x \in E |  x < a\}$ for some $a \in E$.

Comment: @user49640 I have edited to explain.

Comment: Okay, but that definition is equivalent to mine in the case of a well-ordered set.

Comment: @user49640 Thanks! and it intuitively makes sence. May I ask for how to prove that for a well-ordered class, all the initial segments are of the form you mentioned?

Comment: If $I$ is an initial segment of a well-ordered class $A$ (according to your definition), but it isn't all of $A$, then let $a$ be the smallest element of $A$ that doesn't belong to $I$. Then you should be able to prove that $I = \{x \in A \mid x < a\}$. In your specific problem, you only really need to show that $I$ is contained in this set.

Comment: @user49640 Sorry I am still confused. My definition only tells me that which elements should we put into the initial segment. Let me try: is that the fact that if $A$ is well ordered, then the subclass of $A\setminus I$ $A$ is also well-ordered and thus it has a least element $a$. So for all elements which is less then $a$, it cannot be in $A\setminus I$ so it must be in $I$. And which left to show is that all the elements $\ge a$ cannot be in $I$. Assume some $b\ge a\in I$, then by definition of initial segment $a\in I$, contradicts $a\in A\setminus I$. Is that correct?

Comment: Your definition *doesn't* tell you what elements to put in the initial segment. It tells you that *if* a certain element is in the segment, then many more must be in the segment. Your argument is almost correct, but, first, I would say that $A - I$ is nonempty, hence has a smallest element, not that it's well-ordered. You're using the fact that $A$ is well-ordered. Second, the definition of "initial segment" shows that since $a \leq b \in I$, we must have $a \in I$, a contradiction.

Comment: Sorry I cannot see that is contradicts the fact that $a$ is the smallest element. Could you please tell me why? I think my definition tells me that $I$ is a class such that for any $i\in I$, if $a\le i$ then $a\in I$. Now I have $a\le b$ where $b\in I$, so I also have $a\in I$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that was a mistake. That's why I edited my comment.

Comment: @user49640 Okay. I see it, thanks a lot for your patient!